# GNU incompatible pointer types warning when using ADTs in C

Tags: c

I have looked for answer to this and I have checked everything that I could understand which got me down to 6 warnings which I can not remove.

I am fairly new to programming and C, I have replicated some sample code that compiles without warnings unfortunately when I compile my version of the code I get 6 warnings. All I am doing is trying to see if the code in a function file will compile cleanly, the main function just returns 0 at this point. If anyone can see what I am missing I would really appreciate the help!

I have three files: main.c, linkliest.c and tinkliest.h. They look like this:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linklist.h"
#include "textio.h"
int main(void){
        return 0;

}
```

Function file:

```
#include "linklist.h"

struct new_letter {
    char letter[2];
    struct new_letter *next;
    struct new_letter *prev;
};
struct new_list {
    List_T current;
    List_T head;
    List_T tail;
};
```

---

make a new node

```
Letter_T Letter_MakeNew(char* letter_in) {

    Letter_T newLetter;
    newLetter = malloc(sizeof(struct new_letter));
    assert(newLetter !=NULL);

    if(newLetter != NULL) {
        strncpy(newLetter->letter,letter_in,2);
        newLetter->next = NULL;
        newLetter->prev = NULL;
    }
    return newLetter;
}
```

---

create a space in memory for the list

```
List_T List_MakeNew(void) {
    List_T newList;
    newList = malloc(sizeof(struct new_list));
    assert(newList !=NULL);

    if(newList!=NULL) {
        newList->head = NULL;
        newList->current = NULL;
        newList->tail = NULL;
    }
    return newList;
}
```

---

put a  node in the list

```
int List_InsertAtHead(List_T thelist, Letter_T letter){
    Letter_T tempPtr = NULL;

    if(thelist!=NULL) {
    /* point new student->next at current head */
            letter->next = thelist->head;   
            tempPtr = thelist->head;
            thelist->head = letter;

            /* if this was the first entry in the list, set the 
            current pointer to point at it as well */ 
            if (letter->next==NULL) {
                thelist->current = letter;
                thelist->tail = letter;
            }
            /* if there are already elements in the list 
            point the previous letter at the new letter */
            else {
                tempPtr->prev = letter;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct new_letter *Letter_T;
typedef struct new_list *List_T;

Letter_T Letter_MakeNew(char* letter);
List_T List_MakeNew(void);
int List_InsertAtHead(List_T list, Letter_T letter);
```

oh and these are the warnings

```
    gcc -g -Wall main.c linklist.h linklist.c
linklist.c:54:17: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'struct new_letter *' from 'List_T'
      (aka 'struct new_list *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                        letter->next = thelist->head;   
                                     ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
linklist.c:55:12: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'Letter_T' (aka 'struct new_letter *')
      from 'List_T' (aka 'struct new_list *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                        tempPtr = thelist->head;
                                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
linklist.c:56:18: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'List_T' (aka 'struct new_list *') from
      'Letter_T' (aka 'struct new_letter *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                        thelist->head = letter;
                                      ^ ~~~~~~
linklist.c:61:22: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'List_T' (aka 'struct new_list *') from
      'Letter_T' (aka 'struct new_letter *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                                thelist->current = letter;
                                                 ^ ~~~~~~
linklist.c:62:19: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'List_T' (aka 'struct new_list *') from
      'Letter_T' (aka 'struct new_letter *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                                thelist->tail = letter;
                                              ^ ~~~~~~
5 warnings generated.
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error in the question body.

Comment: And please reduce the example.

Comment: Besides posting the actual errors (as is, unformatted and unmodified) also please point out *where* in the posted source the errors are.

Comment: What is `struct new_letter_adt` where is it defined?

Comment: Sorry folks, I just realised I had not posted the errors whoops! As you can now see they all happen in the InsertAtHead function but I am not sure if that is where my mistake really lies. The new_letter definition has been updated, I will update my post, you guys are fast! Thanks a lot

Comment: I feel these error messages are quite self-explanatory. For example: "*assigning to 'List_T' ... from 'Letter_T'*" So what?

Comment: why do you mention 'ADTs' in the title while it is not explicited in question ? Are they known construction/libraries of abrstraction ( like http://sourceforge.net/projects/catl/) ?

Comment: If `List_T` shall handle anything (but other `List_T`)  it should have any members referring to such thing. Could it be that all of `List_T`'s members shall be of type `Letter_T` but `List_T`?

Comment: where did you get that code sample ?

Comment: Hi Philippe, I thought I had defined my structs as ADTs which is why I mentioned it and the code is replicated from a university example.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into other issues, the warnings are because you're trying to assign pointers to `new_list` to variables typed as pointer to `new_letter`, and vice versa.

Each of your structures' elements are pointers to structs of the same type, so trying to assign a pointer to any other type triggers the warning.